# What unit of time does timeIntervalSinceDate return?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

What unit of time does timeIntervalSinceDate return? Is it seconds, milliseconds or something else?

The documentation says that it returns an NSTimeInterval, but what *unit of time* is that value?

Comment: From [NSTimeInterval reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69): Used to specify a time interval, in seconds. `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`. NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds

Answer (score 98, accepted):

It returns the number of seconds, as an `NSTimeInterval` value.

From [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimeinterval?language=objc#):

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` isn't really an object. It's just a double value.

Comment: Actually, `NSTimeInterval` is _always_ specified in seconds.

Comment: How do I get at the milliseconds if it's in seconds?

Comment: Since 1 second = 1000ms, `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:foo] * 1000` should be milliseconds.

Comment: @esqew - Ah, I forgot about that. NSTimeInterval has a decimal point - and numbers following it.

Answer (score 7):

Well the `NSDate` [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate:) show the function prototype as:

`- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate`

And the Foundation Data Types [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) states:

> NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields
>   sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.